# Number of ways to draw a 10, J, Q, K, A , given the deck only has 13 cards of the same suit?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Not sure if I'm reasoning about this the right way. I think this is a permutation problem, and there would be 5! ways to draw it, since the 1st card can be any of the 5 required ones, the 2nd card would be any of the 4 required ones, etc...

But doesn't permutation imply order matters? I don't see the order of drawing the cards mattering in this case, so I'm not sure if this is actually a combination problem. But if it were, there are only (1 choose 1) ways to choose each of the required cards, meaning there's only 1 way to draw a full house...which intuitively makes no sense because there's obviously more.

Comment: Not sure what you would like to know here. A full house is formed by a pair of one rank and a triplet from another rank. For instance a pair of two's and a triplet of kings. So with 13 cards of the same suit you can't form a full house at all.

Comment: Sorry I misworded the question, I will clarify it in an edit

Comment: "Only 13 of the same suit" could mean that each suit has 13 cards (like a regular 52-card deck) or it could mean there are only 13 cards altogether. But once you imply the deck is nonstandard, it could consist only of face cards and tens (with duplicates of some cards) for all we know. You also don't say how many cards you draw. I suggest editing again to explain why you need to know this particular fact, being much more careful to give exactly the information you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your question on the subject of whether order matters.  You say "number of ways", but at the start you write like drawing $10,J,Q,K,A$ is a different way from $A,K,Q,J,10$, then at the end you treat them the same.  You are correct that if order matters there are $5!$ assuming you are drawing five cards and if order does not matter there is just one.

The probability of getting these five cards doesn't change because the sample space is much larger if order matters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood, but if you are asking how many ways to obtain a combination of 10,J,Q,K,A , then, since there are 4 cards of each, there are 4 ways to get a 10 -- one for each suit , and each choice can be combined with the others-- so the total is $4^5=2^{10}$ . Of course, if you want all the cards in the same suit, then , of course, there is just one way, since there is only one of  10,J,K, Q,A in each suit.